# tuckey urlrewrite returns 404 not found

Tags: java, jersey, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using Jersey framework and the endpoint I have is `/v1/users/{user_id: \p{XDigit}{8}}/orders/{order_id: \p{XDigit}{8}}`.

What I need is to rewrite the url `/v2/users/{user_id: \p{XDigit}{8}}/orders/{order_id: \p{XDigit}{8}}` to the above url.

I am using tuckey for url rewrite. And following is my urlrewrite.xml.

```
<rule>
    <from>^/v2/users/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})$/orders/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})$</from>
    <to>/v1/users/$1/orders/$2</to>
</rule>
```

By sending request `curl 'localhost:8080/v1/users/11111111/orders/11111111'`, I am hitting the right endpoint, but when I try to `curl 'localhost:8080/v2/users/11111111/orders/11111111'`, I an getting 404 NOT FOUND response.

And when I change my urlrewrite.xml to following

```
<rule>
    <from>^/v2/users/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})/orders/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})</from>
    <to>/v1/users/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})/orders/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})</to>
</rule>
```

I am getting error saying that `You did not supply enough values to fill path parameters`.

Any idea why I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/v2/users/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})/orders/([A-Fa-f0-9]{8})$</from>
    <to>/v1/users/$1/orders/$2</to>
</rule>
```

Note that you have used one extra '$'.
In RegEx, '$' means 'end of the sentence'.

Good luck.